# How to run topojson from Powershell?

Tags: geojson, json, node-js, topojson, powershell

I have already installed node.js and used it to install topojson via `npm install topojson`. But when I run command like `topojson input.geojson -o output.topojson`, I get the familiar error of

> topojson : The term 'topojson' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I tried adding the `C:\Users\me\node_modules\topojson` to the `Path` System Variable but it doesn't work.

Edit. Aside from my comments, it's `geo2topo input.geojson -o topo_out.json` that works. Loaded the output file in QGIS and it works.

Comment: Looks like *"This package has been deprecated"*, maybe try the [topojson-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/topojson-client) instead.

Comment: I installed both topojson-client and topojson-server but both "cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system". It seems like I have to tweak my computer to allow node.js scripts to be run.

Comment: The workaround is this and I can now run topojson https://stackoverflow.com/a/18533754/12779978 And I ran `npm uninstall topojson-client` and `npm uninstall topojson-server` and the topojson command still works.